# How can I tell what DLL started a thread and what address space a DLL owns for an external DLL?

Tags: multithreading, dll, directshow, access-violation

I have a Delph 6 DirectShow application that exchanges audio with Skype via sockets.  I am getting an intermittent access violation in one of the threads started by one of the DLLs loaded by the Filter Graph when the DirectShow filter chain is ran.  The DLL does not belong to me so I don't have the source code.

I have examined the Event Log and I see this relevant excerpt when the Filter Graph is ran :

```
Thread Start: Thread ID: $00000804. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Module Load: QCap.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $757F0000. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $00000608. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $0000259C. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $00002778. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
ODS: DXCHAIN, STARTING> DXCaptureFilterComponent1 succeeded Process Test.exe ($CE4)
ODS: DXCHAIN, STARTING> DXChainComp_mic2skype Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Module Load: DSOUND.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $73F10000. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
ODS: (TPushSourcePinBase_wavaudio.Create) Construction succeeded. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
ODS: (TPushSourcePinBase_wavaudio.Create) Construction succeeded. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Module Load: wavdest.ax. No Debug Info. Base Address: $10000000. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
ODS: (TPushSourcePinBase_wavaudio.DecideBufferSize) Resulting buffer size for audio is: 800 Process Test.exe ($CE4)
ODS: (TPushSourcePinBase_wavaudio.DecideBufferSize) Resulting buffer size for audio is: 800 Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $000027E0. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $00001DF0. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $0000176C. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
Thread Start: Thread ID: $0000083C. Process Test.exe ($CE4)
```

Note, the ODS lines are the result of "debug print" statements to the Debug Monitor window (OutputDebugString)

The thread that threw the AV in trial documented above was $0000176C.  The thread is **always** the 12th thread created and the location reported by the debugger for the AV is **always** **$77BEFOOF**.  My questions are:

1) How can I tell which of the dynamically loaded DLLs owns the faulting thread?

2) Is there a way to find out the start and end memory locations for each DLL, even those that I don't have source code for, so I can see what DLL contains the **$77BEF00F** address location?

3) Has anyone ever had trouble with an application that mixed DirectShow chains and sockets?  Any caveats or tips you can throw me?  The DirectShow chains in my application mix in audio data coming in from sockets and send data to sockets.

**UPDATE**: Using Roman R's Process Explorer tip I have tracked the AV fault location of **$77BEFOOF** to **msacm32.dll**, which is the Microsoft Audio Compression Manager (shown as "Microsoft ACM Audio Filter" in the Process Explorer *Description* field.)  If anyone has any field experience with problems with that DLL, please share.

Answer (score 2):

Threads don't belong to DLLs, they belong to processes. You will normally want which DLL started a thread, so you will chcek thread call stack and see what are the entries at the very bottom - this will suggest who is the thread starter.

[image: WinInet's Thread]

DLL is mapped into process at certain base address, you can query this programmatically via `PSAPI` (e.g. [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), or [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can get it to you interactively (columns `Base`, `Size`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the title and some of the wording of my post to indicate that I'm looking for the DLL that started a thread, not owns it.  Unfortunately the Delphi debugger does not show anything on the stack for the thread that faulted, and the CPU window just shows a large block of assembler instructions without any useful contextual labels.  Is there a way to trap the CreateThread() call or some other way to try to determine more accurately which DLL started a thread?

Comment: If you get a chance please comment on my update above regarding the Microsoft Audio Compression Manager.

Comment: If you ever have AV, this time or in future, always attach full call stack of the faulting thread. This is what is helpful. I remember a problem with some `ACM` driver, but details faded out. My clue is that you possibly build a media type incorrectly and a driver does not properly checking/validating it and it leads to AV.

Comment: See my reply to your full call stack comment on the other comment thread we have going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310876/how-to-debug-an-access-violation-in-the-microsoft-audio-compression-manager-in-a